# JavaScript HashTable Class Unexpected Token Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, es6-class

I'm learning about Hash Tables and following an example I found but my code will not run and I cannot figure out what is wrong. I've tried to run it using node.js in my terminal as well as Quokka within visual studio code.

```
class HashTable {

    setItem = (key, value) => {};

    getItem = key => {
        return "";
    };
 }

 const myTable = new HashTable();
 console.log(myTable);
```

When I run this on the terminal using "`node HashTable.js`" I get

```
setItem = (key, value) => {};
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token [at the equals sign (=) after
>   'setItem'].

I'm thinking it could be an ES6 related issue but can't find a solution. I've checked and I have installed the latest version for both visual studio code and node.js.

Comment: There is an issue with the Node version. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields. Support for Class Field in Node requires version > 12. I tested on 12.16.1, this code snippet works fine.

Comment: Thanks, Ozgur. That was it. I hadn't properly updated Node.